# how to chart 25th - 75th percentile of variables in dataset as a geom_ribbon in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset in R

```
data <- structure(list(Month = c(-12, -11, -10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, 
-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), One = c(0, 
0.0371801698032526, 0.0253784271272539, 4.93794886360344, 9.76530121319971, 
10.0075933665278, 9.96656448930515, 13.8545126430519, 14.20886974768, 
14.1376488588403, 14.1265599731044, 14.1448566345685, 14.0883033173158, 
14.2164327517825, 14.2119443932704, 14.2757609306801, 14.3451694347538, 
14.3317547632435, 14.2856854834137, 14.3203936957668, 14.8295953287565, 
13.1313072763, 10.6676724910079, 10.6707087335308, 11.3508270586621
), Two = c(0, 1.55059605628171, 2.90098899675787, 2.52208508425239, 
2.76160247919427, 2.82755723437502, 2.92502663906957, 3.7032964286607, 
4.11196361182616, 4.82943043510859, 4.46291318957702, 4.82845456179123, 
5.4622247769475, 6.43190962937046, 6.98263540539801, 7.20163674078652, 
9.10165559829419, 10.8842483335773, 12.0785744632994, 12.6086878907212, 
13.36781455118, 13.6490640541824, 13.6820283407892, 13.474120910704, 
14.0116053191804), Three = c(0, 0.6029399821327, 1.46635485037986, 
1.78624218305855, 1.82373507674815, 1.58726549175668, 2.19858907437077, 
-1.141813530415, -3.37221561837822, -6.0331024859166, -9.61907469070629, 
-13.5343428600961, -20.6043206367254, -24.2170605593005, -23.8753682360845, 
-24.8946715592537, -25.938060044939, -26.7942012507106, -26.3751590459947, 
-28.3057418988061, -33.5997725980671, -37.80980929247, -39.2098053547741, 
-46.0426895446793, -49.950514238462), Four = c(0, -1.16086255895813, 
-3.47299733077671, 0.647124631130547, 2.4524322993544, 4.58897676236837, 
5.12767427031656, 5.54526270357473, 2.88619917175126, 1.48726502786853, 
1.71797168563754, 1.08909262328577, 2.52875095498823, 4.45500416491734, 
4.43960462240841, 5.50931159542064, 6.21129493590505, 5.73343498433668, 
5.02592585101251, 5.87512138863291, 1.45896312438867, -1.5875598983254, 
-3.81681931364961, -6.36456743193832, -6.91045577677611), Five = c(0, 
-2.85325935248144, -8.70194277089187, -6.95394549494022, -6.57894420754355, 
-7.60258856749654, -10.9370855589135, -15.7841413643393, -19.0075109451429, 
-18.0987204213281, -20.1957232538571, -20.8946849076237, -22.1784211318351, 
-24.9524903676304, -23.2423550018128, -24.6064646411457, -26.9265588661482, 
-28.5978727254016, -33.9188405660625, -43.4440647047705, -50.8206174285407, 
-79.6333218248734, -79.2418868480403, -77.2480428010932, -77.595033598265
), Six = c(0, -2.08355796923112, -1.78456827518316, -4.40370757917092, 
-0.789023179837778, 0.397574673087897, -1.6956899186231, 0.947525440880603, 
-2.46055530817029, -0.862526740245739, 3.99371074359077, 4.57585194465909, 
2.63846105998198, 0.537088998616364, -8.85159603094971, -13.6346856482972, 
-10.3219069516894, -8.14684718949907, -12.780417621112, -8.30497090776499, 
-8.89310933278524, -14.471829592137, -39.3231415169117, -44.2466113246124, 
-41.0783675424655), Seven = c(0, -4.05269834453494, -2.28664808761605, 
-4.29816913811201, -5.37701805810242, -1.58111867914905, -9.79798954679481, 
-7.39164087686512, -7.86754129910567, -6.98238468467489, -4.02523422705539, 
-4.18362937257872, -8.75444024292424, -20.707406438733, -34.3628344852653, 
-31.2830727277137, -23.7865641766079, -21.2047288766897, -24.6931116464697, 
-20.948706040334, -18.9668486288461, -12.1905208754137, -7.45810249947987, 
-9.51711194707747, -6.73333673117873), Average = c(0, -1.13709457385543, 
-1.69334774145754, -0.823203064311175, 0.579726517573254, 1.46075146878145, 
-0.316130078752762, -0.0381426507787817, -1.64297009136281, -1.646055715764, 
-1.36269665424414, -1.99634305371342, -3.83134884317875, -6.31950311728246, 
-9.24256704757651, -9.63316932993185, -8.1878528672045, -7.68488742302051, 
-9.48247758313048, -9.74275436807924, -11.803424997702, -16.9875243075339, 
-20.6714363858655, -22.753456200738, -22.4150393584721)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

I'm trying to create a chart with a concept similar to this below, which has the mean (average) plotted as a black line and then the 25th-75th percentile of all the data in my dataset shaded as a geom_ribbon.

[image]

I'm obviously able to plot the average line as a geom_line so far, but I'm a bit unsure of a simple way to overlay the 25th-75th percentile of all the variables in my dataset (`one` to `seven`) as a `geom_ribbon`. Any ideas on how this can be done?

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%  {
  ggplot(., aes(Month, Average)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 'dashed')
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be simply to summarize your data frame as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

longdat <- data %>% 
  select(-Average) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(Average = mean(value),
            Q25 = quantile(value, 0.25),
            Q75 = quantile(value, 0.75))
```

Then your plot could be:

```r
ggplot(longdat, aes(Month, Average)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Q25, ymax = Q75), fill = "orangered", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(y = "Value", title = "Values per month with interquartile range")
```

[image]

A slightly more sophisticated method would be to use quantile regression to find a smooth estimate of the interquartile range:

```r
library(quantreg)
longdat <- data %>% 
  select(-Average) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) 

mod25 <- qgam(value ~ s(Month), data = longdat, qu = c(0.25), 
              argGam = list(gamma = 0.05))
mod75 <- qgam(value ~ s(Month), data = longdat, qu = c(0.75), 
              argGam = list(gamma = 0.05))

pred_df <- data.frame(Month = seq(-12, 12, len = 100))
pred_df <- cbind(pred_df, 
                 Q25 = predict(mod25, newdata = pred_df),
                 Q75 = predict(mod75, newdata = pred_df))

ggplot(pred_df, aes(Month)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Q25, ymax = Q75), fill = "orangered", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value), stat = "summary", fun = mean, data = longdat) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(y = "Value", title = "Values per month with interquartile range")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good answer, thanks Allan.
I would fit the median as well (using `qgam`, not `quantreg`), while increasing `k` and decreasing `gamma`. The `cqcheck` are ok.

```
library(qgam)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

longdat <- data %>% 
  select(-Average) %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) 

mod25 <- qgam(value ~ s(Month, k=20), data = longdat, qu = 0.25, 
              argGam = list(gamma = 0.01))
mod50 <- qgam(value ~ s(Month, k=20), data = longdat, qu = 0.50, 
              argGam = list(gamma = 0.01))
mod75 <- qgam(value ~ s(Month, k=20), data = longdat, qu = 0.75, 
              argGam = list(gamma = 0.01))
summary(mod25)
summary(mod50)
summary(mod75)

pred_df <- data.frame(Month = seq(-12, 12, len = 100))
pred_df <- cbind(pred_df, 
                 Q25 = predict(mod25, newdata = pred_df),
                 Q50 = predict(mod50, newdata = pred_df),
                 Q75 = predict(mod75, newdata = pred_df))

ggplot(pred_df, aes(Month)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Q25, ymax = Q75), fill = "orangered", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Q50)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  labs(y = "Value", title = "Median values per month with interquartile range")

par(mfrow=c(3,1))
cqcheck(obj = mod25, v = c("Month"))
cqcheck(obj = mod50, v = c("Month"))
cqcheck(obj = mod75, v = c("Month"))
```

[image]

[image]